# Vertically align long button across 2 rows

Tags: html, css

I've recently picked up web development and I'm making a basic JS calculator. I'm trying to make the equals and addition buttons longer and span across 2 "rows" vertically. I tried using `position: absolute` but that gave me weird results and increasing the margin but that also didn't give me the results I wanted either.

https://jsfiddle.net/41xmkpbc/

Comment: Using [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) or [html table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) with [rowspan](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_rowspan) will be better choice of implementation for these type of cases.

Comment: Try to use flexbox for proper wrapping in row the buttons. Flexbox has relativly good fallback to older browsers.

Comment: table would be the wrong use as it is not ment for styling purpose just displaying data. The correct tool would be CSS-Grid. Flexbox could do that too, has issues hoever if you need to control width and height at the same time as you need for a tabel like layout. Compability is a minor sisue as the only browser nto supporting CSS-Grid is the ancient IE. Flexbox is also supported in IE 10  11 hoever have different default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eas task with using a CSS-Grid for styling as in the sampel below. I removed your contaienrs for the row lines as they are not needed and will potencially break the CSS-Grid. USe `gird-row: span 2;`to have an element span 2 rows. same for the calculator text field, use `grid-column: span 4;`

```css
header {
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: lightgray;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: darkgray;
}

button:active{
  background-color: darkgray;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 3rem 2rem;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

#calculator-form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.calculator-text {
  grid-column: span 4;
  background-color: #8bac0f;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 26px;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
}

#plus,
#equals {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <form id="calculator-form">
    <div class="calculator-text"> 0 </div>
    <button id="clear" class="operator" value="clear">Clear</button>
    <button id="division" class="operator" value="/">/</button>
    <button id="multiply" class="operator" value="*"> *</button>
    <button id="minus" class="operator" value="-">-</button>
    <button id="seven" class="number" value="7">7</button>
    <button id="eight" class="number" value="8">8</button>
    <button id="nine" class="number" value="9">9</button>
    <button id="plus" class="operator" value="+">+</button>

    <button id="four" class="number" value="4">4</button>
    <button id="five" class="number" value="5">5</button>
    <button id="six" class="number" value="6">6</button>

    <button id="one" class="number" value="1">1</button>
    <button id="two" class="number" value="2">2</button>
    <button id="three" class="number" value="3">3</button>
    <button id="equals" class="operator" value="equals">=</button>


    <button id="zero" class="number" value="0">0</button>
    <button id="decimal" class="operator" value=".">.</button>

  </form>
</section>
```